# Как определить элемент в рулетке

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть готовая рулетка, она крутится и при остановке на элементе его рамки горят зелёным. Мне надо узнать, что это за элемент.

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="arrowup"></div>
  <div class="arrowdown"></div>
  <div class="window">
    <ul class="list">

    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Strawberry.png" alt="1" id='a1'></li>
      <li><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Cherry.png" alt="2" id='a2'></li>
      <li><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Apple.png" alt="3" id='a3'></li>
      <li><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Lemon.png" alt="4" id='a4'></li>
      <li><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Kiwi.png" alt="5" id='a5'></li>
      <li><img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/128/Pear.png" alt="6" id='a6'></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p style="text-align: center">
  <button class="button">Кнопка</button>
  <div class="win">
    <ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $(".list li").clone().appendTo(".list");
      }
      $('.button').click(function() {
        $('.window').css({
          right: "0"
        })
        $('.list li').css({
          border: '4px solid transparent'
        })

        function selfRandom(min, max) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }
        var x = selfRandom(50, 100);
        console.log('вам выпало ' + x)
        $('.window').animate({
          right: ((x * 130) + (x * 8 - 12) - 119)
        }, 10000);
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log(x)
          $('.list li:eq(' + x + ')')
          $('.list li:eq(' + x + ')').css({
            border: '4px solid #00ba00'



          })
        }, 10500);
      });
    });
  </script>
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: Я ничего не понял

Comment: selfRandom(50, 100); - даёт значение от 50 до 100... где в коде такие значения?

Comment: selfRandom(50, 100); храниться в переменной x , она нужна что бы рулетка прокручивалась рандомно px . А не все время например по 100px в лево

Answer (score 0):

Подход в целом неверный. Надо не от сгенерированных пикселей отталкиваться и искать, что это за картинка, а сделать так:

1. в data атрибут картинок вписать числа 1,2,3, и т.д. В общем пронумеровать.
2. Создать массив с числами от 1 до количества кортинок (например 5)
3. Сделать рандом именно на числа из массива
4. Соотнести число из массива и картинку...и только тогда эту картинку отображать и выделять.